# Why should we check irq_fpu_usable before accessing using ASENI instructions

Tags: linux-kernel, x86, kernel, x86-64

In Kernel we check irq_fpu_usable before using any of AESNI x86 asm related
instruction.
 Corresponding kernel code. 
 File: arch/x86/crypto/aesni-intel_glue.c

```c
static int ablk_encrypt(struct ablkcipher_request *req)
{
  ...
    if (!irq_fpu_usable() { 
         Dont use AESNI instruction. 
    } else {
         USe AESNI instruction. 
    }
}
```

1. Why should we check the FPU is available for using AESNI instructions?
2. Will AESNI intructions make use of the FPU?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AES-NI uses XMM registers, which are part of the FPU state.

Comment: @GuruswamyBasavaiah Except that you didn't actually accept the answer (by clicking the grey V mark beside it.

Answer (score 2):

Generally the kernel tries to be lazy when saving and restoring state as it bounces between kernel and user-space as it's a fairly expensive activity. This is especially true with modern SIMD type instructions which can add a fair number of registers to be saved. As a result it tracks when user-space uses them so it can save/restore their state if required.

The the case of irq_fpu_usable() it's actually checking to see if it's in an interrupt where save state is done lazily when required. However if the kernel get's it IRQ while in kernel space it can only safely do that if the kernel wasn't already using the FPU.

Comment: what happens if kernel gets IRQ while in kernel space and it is using FPU ?